# Upgrade zen theme (7.x-3 to 7.x-5.5)?

Tags: drush, theming

Presuming I have zen-7.x-3.x + a sub-theme, how do I go about uprading to zen-7.x-5.x? Perhaps using drush?

I am in awe of the people who wrote these pages:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/219527
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1588244

Comment: Have you tried to update it just like any other theme / module in your system? Any particular problems?

Comment: Hey, how the **** is this too broad? I have "zen 7.x-3.3". I want to get started with zen 5 and SASS / Compass, using drush, ideally. What do I do? Uninstall zen and reinstall? Will this break my existing sub-theme? There are NO PUBLIC INSTRUCTIONS on what to do in the common case when one has an older Zen installed and wants a newer Zen.

Comment: @Molot I usually update everything (not particular modules) via "drush up", because otherwise I need to figure out the module codename, and drush doesn't print that. But I've tried HectorPlus's "drush up zen" and it refuses to move from the 3.x branch to the 5.x branch. Obviously, "drush up" with no args also says there are no updates.

Answer (score 1):

You can run 
drush up zen, it will update the zen theme, but not the subtheme 
Please do a backup before running this command

Comment: That says "No code updates available." I don't think it wants to move from Zen 3 to Zen 5.